# How to skip #N/A in a for loop while leaving it as is and continuing on?

Tags: excel, vba

I am running this for loop through my code, but some cells in Column AV have #N/A there and is throwing an error. The rest does what I want so far but it stops if it hits the #N/A. I found some thing using like IFERROR and ISNA but I couldn't figure out how to put it into my code. I just want to ignore the #N/A and move onto the next row while leaving the #N/A where it is. I just want to skip it and continue the code. How would I be able to do that with this?

```
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngRows As Long
'Find the last row in Column A
lngRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For lngRow = lngRows To 2 Step -1

        If (LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP to ADP").Cells(lngRow, "AV").Value) = "lu" _
            Or LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP to ADP").Cells(lngRow, "AV").Value) = "st" _
            Or LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP to ADP").Cells(lngRow, "AV").Value) = "so") _
            And LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP to ADP").Cells(lngRow, "AU").Value) = "union" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP to ADP").Cells(lngRow, "AW").Value = "MATCH"

        End If

Next
```

Thank you for all help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use an error handler. The `On Error Goto` statement instructs Excel to jump to a different code line if an error occurs. The most simple form to use it is:

```
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngRows As Long
Dim s as String

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP to ADP")
    'Find the last row in Column A
    lngRows = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next             
    For lngRow = lngRows To 2 Step -1
        s = ""
        s = LCase(.Cells(lngRow, "AV").Value)
        If (s = "lu" Or s = "st" Or s = "so") _
        And LCase(.Cells(lngRow, "AU").Value) = "union" Then
            .Cells(lngRow, "AW").Value = "MATCH"
        End If
    Next lngRow
    On Error Goto 0
End With
```

There are additional changes to your code. First, there is no need to de-reference `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP to ADP")` each and every time it is refered to, so use it in a `With` block.
Secondly, there was a slight mistake where you calculate the end row. The `range` was not referenced explicitly as being on that sheet, it could be any sheet active at the moment when the macro runs. The `With` block takes care of that now.
Lastly, it is more economical to store an intermediate value if it is used multiple times, and costs a function call. It makes the code more readable, too.
**edit:**
A `On Error Goto` statement activates an error handling routine. If we use it here, a second runtime error would not be ignored. Instead, using `On Error Resume Next` just skips the next, possible offending, line. All #N/A field are now ignored.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I like how you fixed up the code it looks much nicer now. I have an issue though. The code kind of works, but after it skips one #N/A, it bugs out on the next one and says type mismatch.  Even though I can see that it skips one already. Maybe I just typed in N/A in that cell I can't remember. But it won't keep going once it hits the error...

Comment: Also you mentioned the intermediate value. Is that the "s" value you put in there? I like how you did that just wondering if that is what you meant.

Comment: You were right, a subsequent runtime error was not caught. I've changed the code and it will now ignore all errors. The elegance in this is that you don't have to change the operational code itself, only add the `On Error` statements. And yes, the value read from the sheet, lower-cased, is used multiple times and so assigned to variable `s`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a test for errors:

```
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngRows As Long
'Find the last row in Column A
lngRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For lngRow = lngRows To 2 Step -1
    IF Not IsError(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP to ADP").Cells(lngRow, "AV") Then

        If (LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP to ADP").Cells(lngRow, "AV").Value) = "lu" _
            Or LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP to ADP").Cells(lngRow, "AV").Value) = "st" _
            Or LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP to ADP").Cells(lngRow, "AV").Value) = "so") _
            And LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP to ADP").Cells(lngRow, "AU").Value) = "union" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SAP to ADP").Cells(lngRow, "AW").Value = "MATCH"

        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the other answer first but it was still stopping on errors. This one just skipped right past them and kept going! Perfect! Thank you very much!